# Create product list by specifying product id's

Tags: prestashop

Is it possible to create a custom product list by specifying product ids?

For example, if I want to display a product list of two products,

Can I do something like `website.com/category.php?id_product=1&id_product=2` ??

Obviously the above doesn't work, but I am convinced there is an easy way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you have to do some work for this, as by default prestashop lists products by categories only, and other options like tags, manufacturers etc. 
In your case of requirements, you can do it like below:

1) Lets consider you want to display a list of products on category pages whom ids are passed in urls like website.php/category.php?id_category=10&id_list=1,5,8,9

2) id_list is our list of ids which we want to display for id_category 10. Now in your category.php controller file, get that id_list and pass it to getProducts member function.

3) In getProducts memberFunction id_list should be an options argument, because we dont want to effect the normal operation. Now if id_list is not null, then you have to make adjustments to the product retrival database query and place something like that

```
   id_product IN (your list of ids passed in)
```

This way only those products will be fetched and returned for whom the ids are provided.

**Note: This is just an idea and not implemented or test. It is just to provide you a way or path**

Thank you

Comment: I managed to solve this:
http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/234472-solved-create-product-list-by-specifying-product-ids/page__p__1154915#entry1154915

Comment: you are welcome. That's good that you posted it on the prestashop forum. For pagination, it will work fine, if you also add the list ids array in where clause in the count section, and then also add the pagination query or limiting query in the fetching products query.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative solution for small amount of products

Product class constructor can get you product by ID.

```
$myProduct = new Product( MY_PRODUCT_ID );
```

So you can do something like

```
$my_ids = array(
  2,
  54,
  ...etc
);

$myProducts = array();

foreach( $my_ids as $id_product )
    $myProducts[] = new Product($id_product);
```

**WARNING:** Every call to Product class constructor can be call to database - this solution is only suitable for small amount of products...

*Works on PS1.6, no need for core editing...*